# Can you populate an object's keys directly from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to *directly* populate an object's keys from an array in JavaScript?

Something like

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
var b = {}

b[a] = [1, 2, 3];

// {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

In other words, the opposite of

```
Object.assign({}, ['a','b','c']); 
// {0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c"}
```

I know I can do it via map and assign, but directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a known number of properties, that can be done using destructuring:

```
 const b = {};
 ([b.a, b.b, b.c] = [1, 2, 3]);
```

Otherwise you have to build key-value pairs, and turn them into an object:

```
 const keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
 const values = [1, 2, 3];

 const result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => [key, values[i]]));
```

Unfortunately there is no native `Array.zip` that would simplify this but some [libraries](https://underscorejs.org/#zip) do support that:

```
 const result = Object.fromEntries(_.zip(keys, values));
```

I think thats quite nice.

---

And no, `b[a] =` will always set the `a` property of `b`, otherwise that would be really confusing.

Comment: I think you might have meant `key` instead of `el` in the map function :)

Comment: Thanks! Not direct - but good to know there is no way to do it directly. In perl @a{"a", "b", "c"} = (1, 2, 3) - not necessarily confusing...

Comment: @simone oh wait, if they are static, then that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
a.reduce( (o,c,i)=>({...o,[c]:i}), {})
```

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];

var b= a.reduce( (o,c,i)=>({...o,[c]:i}), {})

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Wanted to post exactly the same. Closest you can get. Do you know if v8 manages to optimize that to O(n) with the spread operator?

Comment: @MoritzRoessler I don't know how smart is v8, if not so smart then my solution is short but not necessarily fast - so question is still open and you can provide more effective solution

Comment: I like your solution a lot. IMO compilers should be smart enough to optimize that, at least in the future. This might even be done by a babel transform.