# Is the spread operator optimizable to O(N)

Tags: javascript, optimization

In reference to that [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858179/1487756), I'm wondering if the spread operator in the following code can be optimized to O(n)?

`["a","b","c"].reduce( (o,c,i)=>({...o,[c]:i}), {})`

GCC compiles that to the following.

`["a","b","c"].reduce(function(a,b,c){var d={};return Object.assign({},a,(d[b]=c,d))},{})`

Since the function is executed within a reduce and no reference is being passed to the initializer, it should be possible to reason about that by means of dataflow analysis.

It's a pure function, it should be highly optimizable.

Is v8 smart enough to do such kind of optimization? - semantically that's a big difference.